# extjs 3.2.0 - Grid Filtering boolean, default to false does not work

Tags: extjs, filtering, extjs3

My filter looks like this:

```
       {
            type: 'boolean',
            dataIndex: 'FutureProfile',
            value:false,
            defaultValue : false
        },
```

This does not add any sort of default filtering for my data.  This brings back every row in the table.

If I do this:

```
           {
            type: 'boolean',
            dataIndex: 'FutureProfile',
            value:true,
            defaultValue : false
        },
```

Everything works fine and when the grid is loaded, the FutureProfile rows only display for items that have the boolean value of true.

So it seems if the value is set to false, extjs completely ignores this and does not send this as part of the ajax call, if it's set to true, the filter is sent via ajax.  How would I make the grid actually default to rows with a false value for FutureProfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after much trial and error.

If you want the default value of a boolean filter to work, you must set active to true:

```
{
            type: 'boolean',
            dataIndex: 'FutureProfile',
            value:false,
            active: true
        }
```